# How to jQuery validate custom radio buttons

Tags: jquery-validate

The form

```
<form id="form_reg" name="form_reg" method="post" action="">
      <input type="radio" id="y" name="opt" value="y"><label for="y"><span>YES</span></label>
      <input type="radio" id="n" name="opt" value="n"><label for="n"><span>NO</span></label>
      <button id="reg_submit" value=" " type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

JS Validation

```
$().ready(function() {
  $("#form_reg").validate({
        rules: {
          opt:{
              required: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          opt: {
              required: "Select one "
          }
        }
  });


  $("#form_reg").validate();
})
```

This works good until I add CSS

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label span {
    width:27px;
    height:25px;
    background:url(/images/radio.svgz) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    width:27px;
    height:25px;
    background:url(/images/radio_a.svgz) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

I guess this is because the default radio buttons are hidden.

How can I validate this form with these custom radio inputs?

Comment: You do not need to call the `.validate()` method twice.  `.validate()` is the plugin's _initialization_ method and only gets called once. Call  `$("#form_reg").validate({...options...})` -> only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform a validation on hidden fields you need to override the default 'ignore' setting with an empty array

```
$(function() {
  $("#form_reg").validate({
        ignore:[],
        rules: {
          opt:{
              required: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          opt: {
              required: "Select one "
          }
        }
  });
});
```

Presumably you have a good reason to want to require a radio button that the user can't see.  For instance when validating a form that is spread across several jquery ui tabs for instance, some fields may be hidden when the form is submitted.

Don't call validate twice on document ready also - although it does no harm there is no point the second call won't do much.

Comment: That works okay, thanks! The reason is that I don't want default button style. That way allows me to design buttons according to the page style.